# Jquery autocomplete UI , Populating key instead of value

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

`enter code here`I am using jquery autocomplete ui.

I have a text box in which user types name of a US state and autocomplete suggestions are made. Here an ajax call is made and json results are returned as expected.

eg. when user types "new" , the json response returned is:

```
{"NH":"New Hampshire","NJ":"New Jersey","NM":"New Mexico","NY":"New York"}
```

What i want is when user clicks a state from the suggest list , eg "New York" , instead of populating the text box with the state name , its state code ("NY" here) be populated.

my current code is :

```
$("#selectAllStateList").autocomplete( { source: "getStateList.html"
         });
```

**********Update* *****

Ok .. now so I have changed the response format . So when I type "de" , I get the response.

```
[{"label":"DE","value":"Delaware"},{"label":"RI","value":"Rhode Island"}]
```

The autocomplete suggestion box shows me DE and RI , but when I click on RI , Rhode Island gets populated in the text box instead of RI which I want.
Can someone help me how to do that.

Thanks in anticipation
Rachit

Answer (score 0):

Got it .. simply changed labels with values.